# Magento 2 - Showing iframe in admin configuration panel

Tags: php, magento, iframe, magento2

I want the users who download and install my extension from the marketplace to go through a registration/login flow. Since the normal `system.xml` file supports only static pages and doing the entire thing using frontend models is too complicated, I'm wondering if I can instead show everything in an iframe?

Showing everything in an iframe gives me lot of advantages like -

Flexibility over design. Magento buttons/elements are ugly.
Being able to use the same iframe my other eCommerce offerings
Much much less engineering time since our team is much more comfortable with JavaScript/CSS than PHP/XML etc
So my question is how to implement the iframe and are there any disadvantages that I'm missing?

I see its possible for [Magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48484/how-to-insert-an-iframe-in-an-admin-panel-field)

Comment: In block file try with $fieldset->addField('map', 'map', array( 'after_element_html' => '<iframe></iframe>' ));

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-type-field-admin-form-magento-2/

Comment: I don't think you need an iframe for this. Just use a form and logic that communicates with your server/api.